# I it necessary to SIM unlock my Samsung Galaxy S2 to use a custom ROM?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom, sim-unlocking

I want to upgrade my Galaxy S II to Android 2.3.5, and my provider only has 2.3.3. So I have to use a ROM from samfirmware.com. Do I have to SIM unlock my phone before installing one of these ROMs? Do I have to root it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galaxy S2 has an unlocked bootloader, which means you can install any rom on it, rooting is not mandatory, some roms have root privileges, some don't.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to SIM unlock. This is separate from the bootloader being unlocked.